The following dependencies do not satisfy the required version: project ':platform_device_id' -> org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.50
Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone x86 in debug mode...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
The Android Gradle plugin supports only Kotlin Gradle plugin version 1.5.20 and higher.
The following dependencies do not satisfy the required version:
project ':platform_device_id' -> org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.50

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2m 32s
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Exited (1).

I have tried to run an old project and that was giving this error still after changing all the versions to latest so then I create a new project and shift all the code to new project but it is still giving this error:

The Android Gradle plugin supports only Kotlin Gradle plugin version
1.5.20 and higher. The following dependencies do not satisfy the required version: project ':platform_device_id' ->
org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.50


Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

In your gradle build file, you specify the versions you need. Here your gradle file is requesting a version for jetbrains kotlin which is too low for Android. Pick a higher version from here https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/org.jetbrains.kotlin.android/1.9.25
